# CMake link to a C++ third party library (open62541)

Tags: c++, cmake, open62541

After multiple hours of researching the internet for an solution (I know there are somewhat similar questions but none were helping) I am close to throwing in the towel, so **help is highly appreciated**.

**Preliminary**:
I want to use the C99 library [open62541](https://github.com/open62541/open62541) for [my own C++ project](https://github.com/makreft/openPubSub). I used the adequate build options for PubSub, since this is what I'm mostly interested in. I also configured the install path to `/home/user/install/open62541`.

**Problem description**:
At first I was able to build everything as expected with this [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/makreft/openPubSub/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt).
But at the moment I try to add the subscription capabilities of open62541 into the project but CMake is refusing to link the library into the project as it is supposed to:

- I copied [this](https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/master/examples/pubsub/tutorial_pubsub_subscribe.c) example code from the tutorials to the project and added `add_executable(subscriber ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tutorial_pubsub_subscribe.cpp)` and `target_link_libraries(subscriber PUBLIC open62541)` to my [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/makreft/openPubSub/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt).
- CMake complains about the following: `undefined reference to 'UA_PubSubConnection_regist'`
- I then went to the lib folder of my install path to find the `libopen62541.so` and
- inspected the shared object with the nm command `nm libopen62541.so | grep UA_PubSubConnection_regist`
- nm returned "t",

so i suppose the build of open62541 cannot be the reason for the linking error.

Comment: I don't understand why find_library isn't all you need?  That function sets an output variable, whose name use you with target_link_libraries for your executable.

Comment: I tried find_library(open62541) in multiple variations but unfortunately non seemed to help.

Comment: If you know the exact path to your library, then just pass this pass to target_link_libraries, like `target_link_libraries(subscriber PUBLIC /home/user/install/open62541/lib/libopen62541.so)`. If this doesn't resolve "undefined reference" error, then the problem is not in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Instead of specifying the full path in `target_link_libraries` I'd instead specify an imported target, since this allows you to attach include directories ect. too and could be a way of specifying different lib files for different configurations.`add_library(open62541 SHARED IMPORTED) set_target_properties(open62541 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/user/install/open62541/lib/libopen62541.so) target_include_directories(open62541 INTERFACE /home/user/install/open62541/include)` or similar.First check, if the installation includes a cmake config file though since this would already contain this

Comment: I will check your suggestions and give an update when i find a solution. thank you a lot.

Comment: So I manged to get the a basic server client connection running. As you suggested the issue was not in the CMakeLists.txt but with the build of open62541. I had  to first downgrade my cmake to 3.12. Only then I was getting helpful debug messages leading me to building the lib without using the encryption option. because when I build the library with encryption enabled, I get and linking error to my systems mbedtls. So for now I think its fine to work without encryption but this might be an issue to solve for me in the near future. Thank you guys for helping me finding a solution, cheers marco.